# Assign a string variable with contents from GlobalTextList

Tags: plc, codesys

Is there a way to assign a string variable with the contents of a string from the GlobalTextList?

Also of import, when it assigns the variable from the GlobalTextList it uses the correct language from the GlobalTextList.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get from static dynamic text list a string in ST?

This function will do it:

```
FUNCTION F_GetText : STRING
VAR_INPUT
    sTextList : STRING;
    sId : STRING;
END_VAR
```

---

```
sTextList := CONCAT('Port_851.',sTextList);
F_GetText := VisuElems.CmpDynamicText.DynamicTextGetText(
    pstTextList:= ADR(sTextList), 
    pstTextIndex:= ADR(sId)
    )^;
```

- If its a static text, give as argument the number as STRING
- If you are using TwinCAT this approach needs the license of HMI. Other option is though ADS and an external program to do the job.

Related post:

[Codesys 3. How to get the translations from static or dinamic text file in ST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313460/codesys-3-how-to-get-the-translations-from-static-or-dinamic-text-file-in-st/64957472#64957472)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do solve this by using the [TextListUtils](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/zMPpTI1nAvRGy8loA2Ct-mmN6GE%2Ffld-TextListUtils;product=TextListUtils;version=3.5.17.0) library.